# I sent 1 IOTA to Bitfinex, transaction is confirmed but money aren't store on my wallet on Bitfinex

Tags: transaction, address, confirmation, bitfinex, balances

It was like that :
1. I wanted to send IOTA to Bitxinex  so  i take adres from my wallet on Bitfinex (according to the instructions) adres is IRFHCFRYIYQYH9T9JNWMT9WUAULEAPWFUJYUPASVVLLPWVONLMVFFUZKODQGDBYGXIFOPKWFXQUEHRKJWHRDX9JKUY
2. After a dozen or so hours - transaction is confirmed by Tangle
(look at https://thetangle.org/transaction/AGMQDQZRRYSFQDC9TNIUPJMPKEQQAVG9YPULYTAGTWCFLOCGY9JMLEE9JBT9IHCMBDRLVAGMRETWZ9999)
3. After an hour (as you can see in Tangle explorer https://thetangle.org/transaction/W9ETYRKVWHDMVBIMHJOHNNHXUW9VYQRSIDBVIQOQJTKHQ9JDQZJ9QJTEPKLXRKFCPPBEJIWYEBKO99999) someone or something executes another transaction as a result my 1 IOTA is taken from the address.
4. In account logs (Bitfinex) there is no trace of these operations, and the account balance is zero. 
I can't understand what happened? Did I make a mistake?
and why Tangle and Bitfinex tell a different story of transactions on adres=IRFHCFRYIYQYH9T9JNWMT9WUAULEAPWFUJYUPASVVLLPWVONLMVFFUZKODQGDBYGXIFOPKWFXQUEHRKJWHRDX9JKUY.
https://thetangle.org/address/IRFHCFRYIYQYH9T9JNWMT9WUAULEAPWFUJYUPASVVLLPWVONLMVFFUZKODQGDBYGXIFOPKWFXQUEHRKJW

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this Question is not about Iota it is about Bitfinex.

Comment: It is not like that. The IOTA Foundation cooperates with the Bitfinex stock exchange, so it also partially prompts for its activities. Bitfinex has been holding my money for more than a dozen hours and I can not use it - and they don't respond to the request services (ticets). who should I ask for help and advice if  not to the IOTA community ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basic practice on Bitfinex. They collect all the iota centralized and keep track of your iota in a Database. This process may take some time. So be patient.
This is not Bitfinex support and if you have questions on Bitfinex use their support please.